# code NOT parsing JSON file

Tags: json, d3.js

CONTEXT :
like many, I am starting off from this example :

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I reused the structure of the miserables.json file, changing only the data, and get the correct visualisation.

here's my COLLECTION.JSON file :

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"COLLECTION","group":0},
    {"name":"Europa","group":1},
    {"name":"Americas","group":2},
...
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":20},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":20},
...
```

NEXT STEP :
I want my nodes to be url/hyperlinks.

I modify my JSON like so (COLLECTION_URL.JSON) :

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"COLLECTION","group":0,"url":".\test.html"},
    {"name":"Europa","group":1,"url":".\test.html"},
    {"name":"Americas","group":2","url":".\test.html"},
...
```

PROBLEM :
the script no longer parses the JSON file

MY DIAGNOSis :
before even knowing if my code to make the hyperlinks is correct, I believe the JSON file is simply  not parsed.

But why ? since the same code parses :

- MBostok's miserables.json
- my personal collection.json

My code is literally MBostok's :

```
// read the JSON file
d3.json("collection.json", function(error, graph) {

//Creates the graph data structure out of the json data
force.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .start();
```

so I don't know what I should add to it to correctly parse my new JSON file.

Can anyone help ?
thanks
enkidu

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser console? If it is not parsed as you expect, what does happen? The snippet collection_url.json has a misplaced quote in the third row.

Comment: As you can certainly see, the stackoverflow code parser identifies your json error. please check line `{"name":"Americas","group":2","url":".\test.html"},` in which number 2 has a quote on its right-hand side.

Comment: Also note, that URLs use forward slashes not back slashes

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. The problem was indeed in the typo in my JSON file. The code parses it correctly now. THANKS EVERYONE !                      I am back to my original problem (creating hyperlinks) but will investigate further. Cheers !